# Split "MediaBox[2.8347 2.83467 609.449 856.063]" into 4 numbers (or Get PDF size)

Tags: php, regex

Please help with regular php.

I need Found this sequence in text:

```
MediaBox[2.8347 2.83467 609.449 856.063]
```

and then split into 4 numbers `(2.8347,2.83467,609.449,856.063)`

Also strings may be

```
CropBox[2.8347 2.83467 609.449 856.063]
```

and so on...

Thanx!!

P.s. Also i found those code to get last 2 numbers: 
in text can be any others

> [xxxx yyyy zzzz oooo]

but i need only those: CropBox[xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx]

```
   $stream = new SplFileObject($path);

$result = false;

while (!$stream->eof()) {
    if (preg_match("/".$box."\[[0-9]{1,}.[0-9]{1,} [0-9]{1,}.[0-9]{1,} ([0-9]{1,}.[0-9]{1,}) ([0-9]{1,}.[0-9]{1,})\]/", $stream->fgets(), $matches)) {
        $result["w"]  = ptToMM($matches[1]);
        $result["h"] = ptToMM($matches[2]);
        break;
    }
}

$stream = null;
```

Comment: Use `/[\d.]+/` to matching digits

Comment: This is not a code writing service, you are supposed to show us what you already tried. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this.**

```
  \d+\.\d+
```

> Explanation

- `\d+` - Will match one or more digit.
- `\.` - Will match `.`.
- `\d+` - Will match one or more digit.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wCPVpq/1)

```
$re = '/\d+\.\d+/m';
$str = 'MediaBox[2.8347 2.83467 609.449 856.063]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: thanx. But in text may exist any other sequence of digits.... sorry, that i miss it in main post.

Comment: @Алексей- what do you mean any other sequence of digits ? some examples ?

Comment: something like this:  Pages 9 0 R/PieceInfo<</HDAG_Tools<</LastModified(D:201812041335)/Private<</PrfID 7448>>>>>>/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
13 0 obj
<</Contents[15 0 R 16 0 R 17 0 R 18 0 R 19 0 R 20 0 R 21 0 R 22 0 R]/CropBox[2.8347 2.83467 609.449 856.063]/HDAG_Tools 35 0 R/ **MediaBox[2.8347 2.83467 609.449 856.063]** /Parent 9 0 R/Resources<</ColorSpace<</CS0/DeviceCMYK/CS1 31 0 R>>/ExtGState<</GS0 32 0 R/GS1 33 0 R/GS2 34 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/ImageC/ImageI]/XObject<</Im0 24 0 R/Im1 25 0 R/Im2 26 0 R/Im3 27 0 R>>>>/Rotate 0/TrimBox[8.504 8.50397 603.779 850.394]/Type/Page>>